# The top 1% own 50% of the world's wealth - how do we turn this into a function?

Tags: statistics, functions

This [Oxfam report states](http://policy-practice.oxfam.org.uk/publications/wealth-having-it-all-and-wanting-more-338125) that 1% of the world's richest own 50% of the wealth.

But to be in the top 1% - you don't have to be a billionaire (assuming a billion is US dollar one thousand million). You only need to [have $US 798K in assets](http://www.bbc.com/news/business-30879173). (ie owning a house in San Fran, London or Sydney).

It follows logically that the next question asked (apart from what on earth are we doing about this desperate income inequality) - what if you have US$100K in assets? Are you in the 2% or the 3% band? It's almost like you need a function to answer this question.

My question is: **The top 1% own 50% of the world's wealth - how do we turn this into a function?**

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle

Comment: I'd rather ask how do we turn that into a peaceful revolution to change things...but  function is also fine. :)

Comment: Yeah me too - but I don't think this is quite the right place to discuss that one.

Comment: $y=134.5^{\frac{1}{x}}$, first term$=134.5$, sum of next $99$ terms $=134.46$

Comment: Could you expand on that one Vikram?

Comment: @hawkeye, it will work only for naturals or integers, not reals, so $x \in \mathbb N$

Comment: Some more data http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-30949796

Comment: Google: Lorenz curve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to know what shall be the definition of the function your are looking for. Because you gave us the data points 1% of population have 50% of assets one can think about the function $$f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$$ with the definition "taking the richest $x$ of the population $f(x)$ gives the ratio of assets they have". You also asked the question

> what if you have US$100K in assets? Are you in the 2% or the 3% band? It's almost like you need a function to answer this question.

For answering this question you need a function $$g:\mathbb R \rightarrow [0,1]$$ with the definition "having an amount $x$ of assets $g(x)$ is the smallest part of the richest population you are part of". Note, that you cannot deduce the function $g$ by knowing $f$! So what function you are looking for?

Another problem: You only gave one argument - function value pair. It is not possible to deduce a function by knowing only one point of its graph. For this you need to assume over properties of the function. For example one can assume, that $f$ has the form $f(x) = 1 - x^n$ which I really doubt because I do not see any reason for this.

I recommend you to look for the [density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) how the assets are distributed (data which says, how many people have an amount $x$ as assets). From this data you can deduce any function you want.