# Compare the 9.9% of the world wealth to the 0.1%

Tags: statistics

I'm trying to:

Create a power law that represents the distribution of the world wealth in every individual in a way that

1. the top richest has ~145B USD (x=1, Jeff Bezos estimated wealth)
2. the power law ends to zero at the 7.8*10^9 individual (7.8B, world population)
3. the integral of the power law function from 1 to 7.8B gives me 300 trillions (current supposed world financial assets, looking for a better value)

I want to do this for its own sake and also because I'd like to compare:

1. the wealth held by the richest 0.1% that I am supposing it would be the result of the integral of the power law function for x from 1 to 7.8*10^6
2. the wealth held by the second richest group intended as the following 9.9%, that I am supposing it would be the result of the integral of the power law function for x from 7.8*10^6 to 7.8*10^7.

I want to compare it because it came to me a doubt about this article:

https://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2018/06/the-birth-of-a-new-american-aristocracy/559130/?fbclid=IwAR3Au6MHjl9SsyRjSenLvpXd4w0hUdtw2MFeVf1PBtWIv0oEpiITixEOUaE

if the power law distribution is too steep, maybe the 0.1% has more than the 9.9%. I started making a messy test here https://www.desmos.com/calculator/q7ffg3q4pr but I guess I came out with just an hyperbola ( f(x) ) and the other function ( g(x) ) should be limited.

Could you give me some suggestions or a direct solution? I am really curious of the result!

PS: I also checked this topic: [The top 1% own 50% of the world's wealth - how do we turn this into a function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118638/the-top-1-own-50-of-the-worlds-wealth-how-do-we-turn-this-into-a-function) which made me try with the g(x) function, and this: [Understanding the Pareto distribution as applied to wealth](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24204/understanding-the-pareto-distribution-as-applied-to-wealth), but I guess "Mathematically, a strict power law cannot be a probability distribution, but a distribution that is a truncated power function is possible where the exponent is greater than 1 (otherwise the tail has infinite area), a minimum value is needed otherwise the distribution has infinite area as x approaches 0, and the constant C is a scaling factor to ensure that the total area is 1, as required by a probability distribution.", even if it's done for a probability distribution, suggests me that I need to make some limitations and add more mathematics to the whole context, alas. Can you guide me through?

EDIT: I also doubted the distribution of wealth could be comparable to the distribution of the world GDP, and as Ross suggested I am looking for a better value.

Comment: Note that GDP is not wealth.  One is a flow of money, the second is a pool of money.  You should look at world net assets for your integral.

Comment: I was just editing and adding that doubt Ross, you're right

Comment: The global financial assets are 300 trillion, I will edit it accordingly, check https://medium.com/design-matters-4/the-worlds-money-in-numbers-d04e6f345a06

Comment: Power-law functions do not go to zero and if you are looking at individuals then you cannot use a continuous function.  You might be interested in https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/13464/wealth-distribution-of-the-super-rich

Comment: thank you Henry!

Answer (score 1):

A power law would be of the form $N(x)=Ax^b$, where $x$ is dollars of wealth and $N(x)$ has units of people per dollar.  The integral from $x=0$ to $x=100$ would then give the number of people with $0$ to $100$ dollars wealth.

You need two equations to set the two constants.  You have two data points in your post which we can use.  One is the total population, which is the integral of $N(x)$.  The second is the total wealth, which is the integral of $N(x)x$.  I will use $h$ for $145 \cdot 10^9$ to save typing.

$$\int_0^h Ax^b dx=7.8\cdot 10^9=\left.A\frac {x^{b+1}}{b+1}\right |_0^h\\
\int_0^h Ax^bx dx=300\cdot 10^{12}=\left.A\frac {x^{b+2}}{b+2}\right |_0^h$$

As you say, we need cutoffs to avoid divergence.  We have one at the high end, supplied by $h$.  At the low end, we can just let the minimum be $1$ instead of $0$ and pretend that everybody has a net worth of at least one dollar.  This gives

$$A\frac {h^{b+1}}{b+1}-A\frac {1}{b+1}=7.8\cdot 10^9\\
A\frac {h^{b+2}}{b+2}-A\frac {1}{b+2}=300\cdot 10^{12}$$

Unfortunately this is very unstable.  For a start we can ignore the terms with powers of $h$ because they will be tiny for negative $b$ like we need.  Dividing the two then gets rid of $A$, leaving $\frac {b+1}{b+2}=38461$, which makes $b$ be just a tiny bit less than $-2$ and $A$ is just about the world population.  What you would like to do is get a number of data points throughout the range and fit $A,b$ from them.

Comment: Thank you! Will try to check everything in detail tomorrow, but I understand the final line :) Curve fitting with matlab has no power law preset but I will try with a custom function! Thanks :)

Comment: Excel will fit to a power law, I believe